# Signed Request Not Received For "Register" Widget

Tags: php, facebook, api, registration

I don't ever receive the Signed Request request variable.

At it's most simple, shouldn't this return signed_request:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=########&xfbml=1"></script>

<fb:registration
  fields="name,birthday,gender,location,email"
  redirect-uri="http://mydomain.com/index.php"
  width="530">
</fb:registration>


<?
var_dump($_REQUEST); //shouldn't the signed_request variable be in here somewhere, there is nothing
?>
```

Comment: I suppose it should! check your FB App setting...also check this [tutorial](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-use-facebook-registration-plugin-as-your-registration-system/15/)

Comment: That link helped, but I'm still struggling to find out why the redirect uri doesn't have any signed_request $_REQUEST in the post. I'll update if I figure anything out. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());

window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init({appId: '%YOUR_APP_ID%', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});
}
//]]>
</script>
<fb:registration 
    class="fb_iframe_widget"
    width="500"
    client_id="%YOUR_APP_ID%"
    fb_only="true"
    fields="name,email,birthday,gender" 
    redirect-uri="%YOUR_REDIRECT_URL%"
>
</fb:registration>
```

You will see signed request at %YOUR_REDIRECT_URL%